# Linear Algebra and NumPy - How array broadcast translates to matrix operations?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numpy

I am familiar with Python's NumPy library and its broadcasting feature that allows to perform operations with vectors and matrices of different sizes. I might be missing the mathematical connection as to what a broadcasting operation translates to. To be more clear, take a look at this example. Suppose we are calculating the euclidean distance between to matrices, $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times n} $ and $ B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $. This would translate (leaving aside the square root operator for clarity) into matrix form as $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}(A - B^{T})^{2} $$.

Now, this operation is not defined in linear algebra, as $A$ and $B$ have different dimensions. However, I can craft NumPy code to make it work. If I unfold the square, the operation becomes
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}A^2 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}(B^T)^2 - 2\sum_{i=0}^{n}AB^T,$$
where the the three terms are now members of, respectively, $\mathbb{R}^{l\times 1}$, $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{l \times m}$. This operations still isn't doable in linear algebra because of the dimensions mismatch that doesn't allow to add and subtract the terms. However, the equivalent numpy code:

```
import numpy as np

l = 3
m = 6
n = 4

A = np.ones((l,n))
B = np.ones((m,n))

A2 = (A**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
B2T = (B**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True).T
AB = np.dot(A, B.T)

result = A2 + B2T - 2 * AB

print(A2.shape)         # prints (3,1)
print(B2T.shape)        # prints (1,6)
print((A2 + B2T).shape) # prints (3,6)
print(result.shape)     # prints (3,6)
```

produces a result, since `B2T` is broadcast when added to `A2`. Now my question is, how is it possible to bypass the mathematical constraint that requires dimensions to match in order to perform addition/subtraction? That is, how can I solve the above problem using just math? It appears to me that I'm clearly missing some mathematical step along the way, but I have no idea which one.

Comment: This is utter mathematical nonsense: it begins with an expression that you acknowledge makes no sense, so what else is to be said?  There cannot possibly be any such thing as the "right result"!

Comment: Okay, I take it the example is a bit off, but it's just an example of how I can get to SOME result (I've edited) despite the operation not being defined in linear algebra. If I rephrase the question as "what linear algebra operation does array broadcasting corresponds to?" does it makes more sense to you?

Comment: The edits help, thank you.  You might be going astray by inquiring about a "mathematical step," when this procedure is explicitly a method of *computation,* as described at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html.  As such it can indeed be framed as a "canonical" way of embedding one tensor space into another (given bases for all spaces involved), but I doubt that's going to be of much help in "solv[ing] the above problem using just math."

Comment: Well, this makes sense. Guess I was looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Thank you!

Comment: Note that (A+B)^2 = A^2+AB+BA+B^2. If AB=BA, then this simplifies to (A+B)^2 = A^2+2AB+B^2. But this simplification is *not* generally applicable to non-commutative systems such as matrix spaces. Also, technically the past participle of "broadcast" is "broadcast".

Comment: Good to know. English is not my first language, as you might have inferred from my poor grammar. Thanks for the advices!

Comment: I just want to mention here that Geometric Algebra/Clifford Algebra allows adding a scalar to a vector (https://www.av8n.com/physics/clifford-intro.htm#sec-addition), which can be generalized for higher dimensional tensor. Though, I am also newly (few hours back :)) introduced with this concept, and have not understood the mathematical details at all, the given resource does not specifically talks about broadcasting.